# Initializing object properties with objects own properties

Tags: javascript

I get the error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'interval' of undefined**

When I try to initialize an object like this:

```
var loop = {
    interval: 5 * 1000,
    maxInterval: loop.interval * 12
};
```

So instead I have to do it like this:

```
var loop = {
    interval: 5 * 1000
};
loop.maxInterval = loop.interval * 12;
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Define "better". There are certainly **other** ways, but unless there are some criteria for evaluation (faster, easier to read, extensible, etc.), who is to say one is "better" than another except by subjective opinion? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No way.

But conceptually all you need is moving the constant one level  up:

```
var defaultInterval = 5000;
var loop = {
    interval: defaultInterval,
    maxInterval: defaultInterval * 12
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using self executing function.

```
var loop = (function () {
    var _ = {};

    _.interval         = 5 * 1000;
    _.maxInterval      = _.interval * 12;

    return _;
})();
```

Comment: Actually probably `var loop = {}; loop.interval = 5 * 1000; loop.maxInterval = loop.interval * 12;` is best.